# Using Twitterizer with ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, twitterizer

I'm trying to use Twitterizer and I can't get to install it on top of MVC4. The problem is caused by the requirements of different versions of the same package: Newtonsoft.JSON. ASP.NET Web API and Twitterizer depends of different versions of the Newtonsoft.JSON. When I force Twitterizer to work with Web API's compatible version of Newtonsoft.JSON, I start to get weird JSON-parsing related errors. How can I get them working together, or is there any way to temprarily disable the Web API, as I don't need it currently.